# TestNG Email Report - PKIX path building exception

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, testng, jakarta-mail, sslhandshakeexception

I am suddenly running in a problem scenario is
I've TestNG project in selenium when I execute a test case after the execution of test case I call the SendMail function written in another class "SendMail.java" using gmail smpt & port 465 it automatically attach the "emailable-report" from output folder after execution of test case it went successfully initially for several number of times but suddenly I am getting the exception shown below

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at automationframework.SendMail.sendMail(SendMail.java:134)
    at automationframework.SendMail.execute(SendMail.java:22)
    at automationframework.Iparkit_Login.sendReportMail(Iparkit_Login.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:308)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1439)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:878)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:814)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:211)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1421)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
```

here is my SendMail.java class

```
package automationframework;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

    public class SendMail

    {
    //reportFileName = TestExecutionResultFileName
    public static void execute(String reportFileName) throws Exception

    {
    String path="D:\\K - Selenium\\SeleniumWorkspace\\iParkit-copy\\test-output\\emailable-report.html";

    String[] to={"receipient@gmail.com"};
    String[] cc={};
    String[] bcc={};//"<AutomationTester>"};

    SendMail.sendMail("sender@gmail.com",
    "*******",
    "smtp.gmail.com",
    "465",
    "true",
    "true",
    true,
    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
    "false",
    to,
    cc,
    bcc,
    "Test Execution Reports",
    "Please find attached Test Suite Execution Report",
    path,
    reportFileName);
    }

    public static boolean sendMail(String userName,
    String passWord,
    String host,
    String port,
    String starttls,
    String auth,
    boolean debug,
    String socketFactoryClass,
    String fallback,
    String[] to,
    String[] cc,
    String[] bcc,
    String subject,
    String text,
    String attachmentPath,
    String attachmentName){

    //Object Instantiation of a properties file.
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.user", userName);

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

    if(!"".equals(port)){
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    }

    if(!"".equals(starttls)){
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",starttls);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
    }

    if(debug){

    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");

    }else{

    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "false");

    }

    if(!"".equals(port)){
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
    }
    if(!"".equals(socketFactoryClass)){
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",socketFactoryClass);
    }
    if(!"".equals(fallback)){
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", fallback);
    }

    try{

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    session.setDebug(debug);

    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setText(text);

    msg.setSubject(subject);

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachmentPath);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentName);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    msg.setContent(multipart);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));

    for(int i=0;i<to.length;i++){
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new
    InternetAddress(to[i]));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<cc.length;i++){
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new
    InternetAddress(cc[i]));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<bcc.length;i++){
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new
    InternetAddress(bcc[i]));
    }

    msg.saveChanges();

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

    transport.connect(host, userName, passWord);

    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

    transport.close();

    return true;

    } catch (Exception mex){
    mex.printStackTrace();
    return false;
    }
    }



}
```

Please help I am struggling on it since 2 days but no solution is working for me

Comment: See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert).

Comment: I've seen but to no avail man

Comment: One Important thing to mention is that same code is working on my other machine

Comment: The FAQ entry describes several reasons why it might work on one machine but not another.  Most of the reasons have nothing to do with the code you wrote.  Please explain everything you did after reading the FAQ entry, and the results you got.  Also, you can [remove all the socket factory stuff](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution of my problem at my own, I had running Avast Anti Virus, I turned it off and now its working like charm...

Comment: Well, duh.  Didn't the FAQ say that was one possibility?  Yes, it did.

Comment: Well it does, but as I told you I executed the same code on my other laptop and suddenly realized that my other laptop is not running any anti virus, and yes FAQ's helped too